# Listiview with custom adapter alway crash on intent to get listview item name

Tags: listview, android-studio, android-adapter

Well, the problem is in the title. I have a listview with a custom adapter. When I try to get the name of the listview item that display in the listview, the system crash. How can i solve it?

```
public class MenuPrincipalCiudades extends ListActivity {

    private AlphabetListAdapter adapter = new AlphabetListAdapter();
    private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;
    List<Row> rows;
    private List<Object[]> alphabet = new ArrayList<>();
    private HashMap<String, Integer> sections = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    private int sideIndexHeight;
    private static float sideIndexX;
    private static float sideIndexY;
    private int indexListSize;

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    JSONArray ciudades = null;
    JSONObject c;
    ListView lv;
    boolean esCancelado = false;
    ArrayList<String> listaCiudades;


    class SideIndexGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
            sideIndexX = sideIndexX - distanceX;
            sideIndexY = sideIndexY - distanceY;

            if (sideIndexX >= 0 && sideIndexY >= 0) {
                displayListItem();
            }

            return super.onScroll(e1, e2, distanceX, distanceY);
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_alphabet);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        listaCiudades = new ArrayList<>();

        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new SideIndexGestureListener());
        listaCiudades.add("New York");
        listaCiudades.add("Panama");
        listaCiudades.add("Spain");
        aplicarEstilo();

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
                AlphabetListAdapter.Section obj_itemDetails = (AlphabetListAdapter.Section) adapter.getItem(position);
                Toast.makeText(MenuPrincipalCiudades.this, "You have chosen : " + " " + obj_itemDetails.text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });

    }






    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void aplicarEstilo(){
        Collections.sort(listaCiudades);

        rows = new ArrayList<>();
        int start = 0;
        int end = 0;
        String previousLetter = null;
        Object[] tmpIndexItem = null;
        Pattern numberPattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]");

        for (String country : listaCiudades) {
            String firstLetter = country.substring(0, 1);

            // Group numbers together in the scroller
            if (numberPattern.matcher(firstLetter).matches()) {
                firstLetter = "#";
            }

            // If we've changed to a new letter, add the previous letter to the alphabet scroller
            if (previousLetter != null && !firstLetter.equals(previousLetter)) {
                end = rows.size() - 1;
                tmpIndexItem = new Object[3];
                tmpIndexItem[0] = previousLetter.toUpperCase(Locale.UK);
                tmpIndexItem[1] = start;
                tmpIndexItem[2] = end;
                alphabet.add(tmpIndexItem);
                start = end + 1;
            }

            // Check if we need to add a header row
            if (!firstLetter.equals(previousLetter)) {
                rows.add(new Section(firstLetter));
                sections.put(firstLetter, start);
            }

            // Add the country to the list
            rows.add(new Item(country));
            previousLetter = firstLetter;
        }

        if (previousLetter != null) {
            // Save the last letter
            tmpIndexItem = new Object[3];
            tmpIndexItem[0] = previousLetter.toUpperCase(Locale.UK);
            tmpIndexItem[1] = start;
            tmpIndexItem[2] = rows.size() - 1;
            alphabet.add(tmpIndexItem);
        }

        adapter.setRows(rows);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        updateList();
    }

    public void updateList() {
        LinearLayout sideIndex = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.sideIndex);
        sideIndex.removeAllViews();
        indexListSize = alphabet.size();
        if (indexListSize < 1) {
            return;
        }

        int indexMaxSize = (int) Math.floor(sideIndex.getHeight() / 20);
        int tmpIndexListSize = indexListSize;
        while (tmpIndexListSize > indexMaxSize) {
            tmpIndexListSize = tmpIndexListSize / 2;
        }
        double delta;
        if (tmpIndexListSize > 0) {
            delta = indexListSize / tmpIndexListSize;
        } else {
            delta = 1;
        }

        TextView tmpTV;
        for (double i = 1; i <= indexListSize; i = i + delta) {
            Object[] tmpIndexItem = alphabet.get((int) i - 1);
            String tmpLetter = tmpIndexItem[0].toString();

            tmpTV = new TextView(this);
            tmpTV.setText(tmpLetter);
            tmpTV.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tmpTV.setTextSize(15);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1);
            tmpTV.setLayoutParams(params);
            sideIndex.addView(tmpTV);
        }

        sideIndexHeight = sideIndex.getHeight();

        sideIndex.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // now you know coordinates of touch
                sideIndexX = event.getX();
                sideIndexY = event.getY();

                // and can display a proper item it country list
                displayListItem();

                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    public void displayListItem() {
        LinearLayout sideIndex = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.sideIndex);
        sideIndexHeight = sideIndex.getHeight();
        // compute number of pixels for every side index item
        double pixelPerIndexItem = (double) sideIndexHeight / indexListSize;

        // compute the item index for given event position belongs to
        int itemPosition = (int) (sideIndexY / pixelPerIndexItem);

        // get the item (we can do it since we know item index)
        if (itemPosition < alphabet.size()) {
            Object[] indexItem = alphabet.get(itemPosition);
            int subitemPosition = sections.get(indexItem[0]);
            getListView().setSelection(subitemPosition);
        }
    }

}
```

The adapter class is this:

```
public class AlphabetListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public static abstract class Row {}


    public static final class Section extends Row {
        public final String text;

        public Section(String text) {
            this.text = text;
        }
    }

    public static final class Item extends Row {
        public final String text;

        public Item(String text) {
            this.text = text;
        }
    }

    private List<Row> rows;

    public void setRows(List<Row> rows) {
        this.rows = rows;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return rows.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Row getItem(int position) {
        return rows.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (getItem(position) instanceof Section) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;

        if (getItemViewType(position) == 0) { // Item
            if (view == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                view = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item, parent, false);
            }

            Item item = (Item) getItem(position);
            TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            textView.setText(item.text);
        } else { // Section
            if (view == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                view = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_section, parent, false);
            }

            Section section = (Section) getItem(position);
            TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            textView.setText(section.text);

           }

        return view;
    }

}
```

Finally, this is my xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:dividerHeight="7.0sp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:divider="#eeeeee"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/sideIndex"
        android:layout_width="40dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[Click here to see how the activity display](http://postimg.org/image/meu0u0fkp/)

If everything works great, when you touch in "Panama" the listview will return Panama. But listview return a error instead.

This is the log:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: mypackage.AlphabetListAdapter$Item cannot be cast to mypackage.AlphabetListAdapter$Section
```

Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because *adapter.getItem(position)* method returns *Item* not *Section*. Therefore you have to change the line

```
AlphabetListAdapter.Section obj_itemDetails = (AlphabetListAdapter.Section) adapter.getItem(position);
```

to

```
AlphabetListAdapter.Item obj_itemDetails = (AlphabetListAdapter.Item) adapter.getItem(position);
```

Comment: Excelent ozo! Thanks for helping me